# Elementary operation $C_2 \to C_2+2C_1$ in matrix equation

Tags: matrices

Use elementary column operation $C_2 \to C_2+2C_1$

> $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

How to do we use operation so validity of equations exists because if perform operation on all three matrix,then I get invalid equation.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to do?

Comment: Your question is not enough clear

Comment: If you can multiply matrices on right hand side you get matrix on right hand side.